# PrimeFaces 3.4.1 Spring 3.2.0RC Hibernate 4.0.1

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

i want to develop my app with PrimeFaces, Spring and Hibernate, and i take this example but it does work .
i dont how to configure applicationContext.xml, web.xml, faces-config.xml, and i don't know if i have missed jar .

i have this error :

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @14,50
>   value="#{customer.lists}": Property 'lists' not found on type
>   comtic.scrum.managedBean.CustomerBean

i use tomcat 7 and JBoss Dev Studio ,primeFaces 3.4.1 , spring-3.2.0.RC1, hibernate-release-4.0.1.Final

my table is customer with (customerId, name, address, createdDate) columns

this a list of jars in WEB-INF/lib :

> 1. antlr-2.7.7.jar
> 2. common-annotations.jar
> 3. commons-beanutils.jar
> 4. commons-collections.jar
> 5. commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
> 6. commons-digester.jar
> 7. commons-logging.jar
> 8. dom4j-1.6.1.jar
> 9. hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
> 10. hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
> 11. hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
> 12. javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
> 13. jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
> 14. jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
> 15. jsf-api-2.1.6.jar
> 16. jsf-impl-2.1.6.jar
> 17. jslt.jar
> 18. mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
> 19. primefaces-3.4.1.jar
> 20. spring-aop-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 21. spring-aspects-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 22. spring-beans-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 23. spring-context-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 24. spring-context-support-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 25. spring-core-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 26. spring-expression-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 27. spring-instrument-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 28. spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 29. spring-jdbc-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 30. spring-jms-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 31. spring-orm-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 32. spring-oxm-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 33. spring-struts-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 34. spring-test-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 35. spring-tx-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 36. spring-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 37. spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 38. spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.0.RC1.jar
> 39. standard.jar

this is Customer.java

```
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Customer generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer customerId;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Date createdDate;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String name, String address, Date createdDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

}
```

CustomerDAO.java :

```
import java.util.List;

import comtic.scrum.customer.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerDao{

    void addCustomer(Customer customer);

    List<Customer> findAllCustomer();

}
```

CustomerDaoImp.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import comtic.scrum.customer.dao.CustomerDao;
import comtic.scrum.customer.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

public class CustomerDaoImpl extends 
       HibernateDaoSupport implements CustomerDao{

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){

        customer.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        getHibernateTemplate().save(customer);

    }

    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer(){

        return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Customer");

    }
}
```

CustomerService.java

```
import java.util.List;

import comtic.scrum.customer.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerService {
    void addCustomer(Customer customer);

    List<Customer> findAllCustomer();

}
```

CustomerServiceImp.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

import comtic.scrum.customer.dao.CustomerDao;
import comtic.scrum.customer.model.Customer;
import comtic.scrum.customer.service.CustomerService;

public class CustomerServiceImp extends 
HibernateDaoSupport  implements CustomerService {

    CustomerDao customerDao;

    public CustomerDao getCustomerDao() {
        return customerDao;
    }

    public void setCustomerDao(CustomerDao customerDao) {
        this.customerDao = customerDao;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){

        customerDao.addCustomer(customer);

    }

    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer(){

        return customerDao.findAllCustomer();
    }

}
```

CustomerBean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="customerService" 
         class="comtic.scrum.customer.service.imp.CustomerServiceImp" >
        <property name="customerDao" ref="customerDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerDao" 
         class="comtic.scrum.customer.dao.imp.CustomerDaoImp" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory">
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

CustomerBean.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import comtic.scrum.customer.model.Customer;
import comtic.scrum.customer.service.CustomerService;

public class CustomerBean implements Serializable {
    //DI via Spring
        CustomerService customerService;

        public String name;
        public String address;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }



        //get all customer data from database
        public List<Customer> customerList(){
            return customerService.findAllCustomer();
        }

        //add a new customer data into database
        public String addCustomer(){

            Customer cust = new Customer();
            cust.setName(getName());
            cust.setAddress(getAddress());

            customerService.addCustomer(cust);

            clearForm();

            return "";
        }

        //clear form values
        private void clearForm(){
            setName("");
            setAddress("");
        }

        public comtic.scrum.customer.service.CustomerService getCustomerService() {
        return customerService;
    }

        public void setCustomerService(
            comtic.scrum.customer.service.CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }


}
```

DataSource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean 
   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
     <value>WEB-INF/classes/config/database/db.properties</value>
   </property>
</bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

HibernateSessionFactory.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
          <value>comtic/scrum/customer/hibernate/Customer.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
     </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>     

</bean>
</beans>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>customer</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>comtic.scrum.managedBean.CustomerBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>customerService</property-name>
   <property-class>comtic.scrum.customer.service.CustomerService</property-class>
   <value/>
  </managed-property>
 </managed-bean>

 <application>
  <resource-bundle>
   <base-name>resources</base-name>
   <var>msgs</var>
  </resource-bundle>
 </application>
</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>Template</display-name>
 <!-- Spring Context Configuration' s Path definition -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <!-- Project Stage Level -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:pf="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>PrimeFaces + Spring + Hibernate Example</h1>
    <pf:dataTable value="#{customer.lists}" var="c">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="customerId"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{c.name}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{c.address}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{c.createdDate}"/>
        </h:column>     
    </pf:dataTable>

    <h2>Add New Customer</h2>
    <h:form>
        <pf:panelGrid columns="3" >
            Name :              
                    <pf:inputText id="name" label="Name" required="true" size="20" value="#{customer.name}">                        
                    </pf:inputText>                 
                <h:message for="name" style="color:red" />

                Address :               
                    <pf:inputTextarea cols="30" id="address" label="Address" required="true" rows="10" value="#{customer.address}">                     
                    </pf:inputTextarea>
                <h:message for="address" style="color:red" />               
            <pf:button outcome="#{customer.addCustomer}" value="Submit">

            </pf:button>
        </pf:panelGrid>
    </h:form>   
</h:body>
</html>
```

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is all that Spring/Hibernate/XML code really necessary to demonstrate the problem? You'd have exactly the same problem when having only a XHTML file and a managed bean class without all that Spring/Hibernate/XML noise. Learn to isolate the problem into 1 or 2 pages. Your question is nearly 10 pages long ...

Anyway, the exception which you got

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @14,50 value="#{customer.lists}": Property 'lists' not found on type comtic.scrum.managedBean.CustomerBean

is just trying to tell you that the `CustomerBean` class is missing the getter method `getLists()`. Add it and make sure that it returns a `List<Customer>`.

```
public List<Customer> getLists() {
    return lists;
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the plural `s` in the property name is by the way strange. It returns only *one* list, right? If I were you, I'd rename it to `#{customer.list}` with a `getList()` getter.

Comment: thanks i change in index.html <pf:dataTable value="#{customer.lists} to <pf:dataTable value="#{customer.customerList()} but i got java.lang.NullPointerException at comtic.scrum.managedBean.CustomerBean.customerList i follow the code i thought that getHibernateTemplate().find("from Customer") return null but i don't know why

Comment: That's a completely different problem. Press `Ask Question` button on right top if you don't understand the new problem and thus can't figure the solution on your own. The current problem has been disappeared and is thus answered/solved.